# Boton Contador de Clicks en Adobe Edge Animate cc

Tags: edge

Estoy intentando hacer un boton que me cuente el número de clicks que doy en ese boton y me muestre el numero en una caja de texto

tengo un

boton < div > llamado "boton1"
y un cuadro de texto < code > llamado "tex" 
en el boton la accion en click

```
var count = 0;
count++;
sym.$("tex").html("Errores "+count);
```

y si hace la cuenta - ya que si var count lo cambio... por ejemplo

```
var count = 5 
count++;
sym.$("tex").html("Errores "+count);
```

cuando doy click me muestra un 6 en el cuadro de texto "tex"
osea que si esta sumando,

pero al seguir dando click deja de contar y se queda en 1

Comment: Que llevas al momento?, Considera editar pues tu pregunta tiene problemas de formato y es casi seguro termine cerrada

Comment: gracias ya edité